# Определить длину подмассива

Tags: java, массивы

Необходимо определить максимальную длину подмассива  у которого все элементы возрастают: X(i) < X(i+1)

Объявил две переменные, одна содержит максимальную длину, другая хранит длину длин. Пробежался по массиву и записал в count значение. Если максимальное значение меньше count, то записал в максимальное значение count. В итоге будут посчитаны все возрастающие последовательности даже если они идут с прерыванием, но как посчитать именно подмассивы?

```
int max = 1;
int count = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    if (array[i] < array[i + 1])
        count++;
}

if (max < count)
    max = count;
count = 1;

System.out.print(max + " ");
```

Comment: Язык программирования какой?

Comment: Язык программирования Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почти правильно написали, только последние строки должны быть в блоке `else`. Т.е. пока последовательность возрастает - увеличиваем счетчик. Как только перестала возрастать (конец возрастающей последовательности/подмассива) - проверяем на максимум и запоминаем если надо, а счетчик сбрасываем в начальное значение.
И сравнение после цикла - на случай если массив завершится на увеличивающейся последовательности, то сравнение с `max` в цикле не сработает.

```
int max = 1;
int count = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    if(array[i] < array[i+1])
        count++;
    else{
        if (max < count)
            max = count;
        count = 1;
    }
}
if (max < count)
    max = count;
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось!

Comment: Спасибо здесь - принятый ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Можно сразу же при инкременте счетчика запоминать максимум, также следует учесть пустой массив.
*(Обновление)* Также стоит дополнительно проверить условие досрочного выхода, когда размер оставшейся части массива не превышает уже подсчитанную максимальную длину:

```java
public static int maxLength(int ... arr) {
    if (null == arr || arr.length < 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    int max = 1;
    for (int i = 1, count = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > arr[i - 1]) {
            if (++count > max) {
                max = count;
            }
        }
        else {
            count = 1;
            if (max >= arr.length - i) {
                break; // отбросить проверку хвоста массива
            }
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Тест:

```java
System.out.println(maxLength());                     // 0
System.out.println(maxLength(2));                    // 1
System.out.println(maxLength(2, 3, 4, 2, 3));        // 3
System.out.println(maxLength(2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 5, 7));  // 4
```

Comment: А зачем на каждом шаге делать проверку с присваиванием для `max`, если можно сделать это 1 раз при окончании последовательности? Это замедляет программу, особенно при длинных последовательностях.

Comment: Чтобы убрать повторную проверку после цикла.

Comment: После цикла проверка 1 раз. А в цикле много раз. И зачем?